# How to order a stream receiving parameter in the request using spring JPA

Tags: java

I need to order the stream from the parameters received above, how can I do this safely and that it works in an ASC and DESC way?

```java
public List<BillToPay> findWithOrderBy(String orderName, String orderDir) {
    List<BillToPay> listBillToPay = this.repository.findAll();
}
```

Comment: can't see any stream here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a stream for this as Spring Data JPA already has overloaded methods that allow sorting. You just need to convert your arguments to the necessary type such as:

```
//Pass the name of the field you want to sort by here, not the actual value
public List<BillToPay> findWithOrderBy(String fieldName, String direction) {
    Sort.Direction dir = direction.equalsIgnoreCase("asc") ? Sort.Direction.ASC 
            : Sort.Direction.DESC;
    List<BillToPay> listBillToPay = this.repository.findAll(Sort.by(dir, fieldName));
    return listBillToPay;
}
```

The JPA method accepts a variable String argument, so assuming you want to sort by multiple fields all in the same direction (not a mix of ASC/DESC) you could easily implement it and barely change anything.

```
//Direction needs to come first as variable parameter must come last in the signature
public List<BillToPay> findWithOrderBy(String direction, String...fieldNames) {
    Sort.Direction dir = direction.equalsIgnoreCase("asc") ? Sort.Direction.ASC 
            : Sort.Direction.DESC;
    List<BillToPay> listBillToPay = this.repository.findAll(Sort.by(dir, fieldNames));
    return listBillToPay;
}
```